# Voice guidance messages configuration in here android sdk

Tags: android, here-api

Is there a way to prevent specific voice guidance messages to be told to the user ?

More specifically, I'd like to prevent the SDK to say to the driver that he arrives to a waypoint or to the route destination.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it by modifying the voice skin to remove the unwanted text.

Steps :

1. find the voice skin you wish to modify in data//files/voice-download/
2. modify the file prompt.lua.

for example change:

```
-- 966: At the end of the road enter the roundabout
["c00c0y00"] = "Au bout de la route prenez le rond-point",
```

to:

```
-- 966: At the end of the road enter the roundabout
["c00c0y00"] = "",
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hacking the voice skin lua files, you can intercept the audio files being played by using the AudioPlayerDelegate and filtering out the file for waypoint and destination:

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-guidance-audioplayerdelegate.html#topic-apiref

You can check whether the current maneuver is a waypoint or destination reached to skip playing the file.